# Knockout js & Dynatree

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-dynatree

Is there any way I can use knockout js in Dynatree ?

If anyone has implemented please do let me know

Thanks,
Anirban

Comment: I haven't used DynaTree but I have written a tree in pure KO under https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI you might want to check it out and see if it would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that shows Knockout loading a View Model via AJAX and then converting the rendered elements into a Dynatree.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/EZgNs/

Comment: IE has a problem loading this fiddle.  It works in FF and Chrome.

Comment: This is the error I see in IE9: "Script from https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch".  This doesn't appear to be a problem with the fiddle itself.